next-auth & keycloak access token problem and showing wrong user after refreshing page
I have a nextjs 14 project. I use "next-auth": "^4.24.5" and Keycloak for authentication. Recently I have found an odd problem. Somedays it does not happen, somedays it happens a lot and I don't know what is the problem.
This is the scenario:
I log in to my panel with a user and go to a page. Then I sign out using a button on my top navbar that uses Keycloak signout function. then I'm sent to sign-in page of Keycloak. I sign in using another user. everything looks fine, but sometimes, when I refresh the panel page that I have landed on after login, or click the back button, or do other things, suddenly after the page is reloaded I see the first user is logged in and not the second user that I had just logged in.
The odd thing is that the access token that is shown for the first user this time differs from the time I logged in with it.
Why does this happen? Is it because of cookies? Then why does the first user suddenly have a different access token when it replaces the second user?
(So this is the whole scenario again: I sign in with a first user then sign out. then Sign in with the second user and after landing in the panel successfully and everything loads without a problem, I refresh the page and when I see the page again, I see the first user information and the access token is never the same)
authOptions:
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import KeycloakProvider from 'next-auth/providers/keycloak';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

async function refreshAccessToken(token: JWT) {
  try {
    const url = `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      // @ts-ignore
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      }),
      method: 'POST',
    });

    const refreshedTokens = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw refreshedTokens;
    }

    cookies().set({
      name: 'accessToken',
      value: refreshedTokens.access_token,
    });

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + refreshedTokens.expires_in * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      ...token,
      error: 'RefreshAccessTokenError',
    };
  }
}

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
    signOut: '/signout',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ID || '',
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET || '',
      issuer: process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER,
      // Add the offline_access scope here
      authorization: { params: { scope: 'openid email profile offline_access' } },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }: any) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        cookies().set({
          name: 'accessToken',
          value: account.access_token,
        });

        return {
          accessToken: account.access_token,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          provider: account.provider,
          exp: account.expires_at,
          user: account.user,
          idToken: account.id_token,
          //@ts-ignore
          user,
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account.expires_in * 1000,
        };
      }

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        return token;
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      return refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
    async session({ session, token }: any) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      if (token) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
        session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
        session.user = token.user;
        session.error = token.error;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
  events: {
    signOut: async ({ token }: any) => {
      cookies().delete({ name: 'accessToken' });
      // Kill the session on keycloak server on behalf of user
      if (token.provider === 'keycloak') {
        await axios.get(
          `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=${token.idToken}`,
        );
      }
    },
  },
};

my axios file:
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { signOut } from 'next-auth/react';
import { getCookie } from '@/utils/cookie';
import errorHandling from '@/services/errorHandling';

export const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL;

const headers: { [key: string]: any } = {};

const axiosApiInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers,
});

axiosApiInstance.interceptors.request.use((req: any) => {
  if (!process.browser && req.headers.common.accessToken) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${req.headers.common.accessToken}`;
  } else if (getCookie('accessToken')) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${getCookie('accessToken')}`;
  }
  return req;
});

axiosApiInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
      localStorage.removeItem('requestedSchedule');
      await signOut();
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (error?.code !== 'ERR_CANCELED' && originalRequest?.responseType !== 'blob') {
      errorHandling(error, ['post', 'put', 'delete'].includes(originalRequest?.method?.toLowerCase()));
    }

    return Promise.reject(error.response);
  },
);

export async function post(url: string, body: any, config = {}) {
  return axiosApiInstance
    .post(url, body, config)
    .then((res) => res)
    .catch((error) => error);
}

export async function get(url: string, config = {}) {
  return axiosApiInstance
    .get(url, config)
    .then((res) => res)
    .catch((error) => error);
}

export default axiosApiInstance;


my middleware:
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|images|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
};
export default withAuth({
  // Matches the pages config in `[...nextauth]`
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
    signOut: '/signout',
  },
});


